# css3 @media queries for multiple browsers

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am following one tutorial about media and responsive patterns here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

i have three different div containers like this:

```
<div>
<div class="customer">
<customer></customer>
</div>
<div class="dates">
Dates comes here
</div>
<div class="addressAndPhases">
  Address and  phases comes here
</div>
</div>
```

and  **css** looks like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    [class*=".customer,.dates,.addressAndPhases"] {
        background-color: lightblue;
        width:100%;
    }
}

.customer{
   float: left;
    width: 27%;
    height: 350px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px;
}

.dates{
      box-sizing: border-box;
      float: left;
      height: 350px;
     width: 22%;  
   padding: 15px;

}

.addressAndPhases{

      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-align: center;
      float: left;
      height: 650px;
     width: 22%;
    padding: 15px;

}
```

i am expecting when width is smaller than 500px, background should be light blue but unfortunately it is not working like this.

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your attribute selector is incorrectly formed `[class*=".customer,.dates,.addressAndPhases"] {}` should be `[class*="customer"],[class*="dates"],[class*="addressAndPhases"]` ... but then again... why don't you just use regular classes?

Comment: @Danield i tried with right syntax(as you suggested) but still its not working. With Regular class ? you mean if i have 3 classes for Normal Version , then i should define 3 more for media query ? this is something i would like to avoid until i dont have any other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you really don't benefit from the asterisk `*`, you'll need to separate the classes in a list:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    [class="customer"],[class="addressAndPhases"],[class="dates"] {
        background-color: lightblue;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Not really any benefit to use those selectors though:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .customer, .addressAndPhases, .dates {
        background-color: lightblue;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Also note that for this to work, you'd need to move this media query below the class definitions. Otherwise they would overwrite your setting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i am able to see  changed back ground color, i was expecting width 100% for all these 3 classes.  but width is not 100% .

Comment: mhh you could try width : 100% !important;

Comment: place it below your other classes, in the "end" of the file. You're first setting them to 100%, then changing them to 27% (etc.) again

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS is out of order. Even if your selector was right for your media query, CSS will abide by the most "recent" declaration. (assuming they're all of equal specificity)

Because you're declaring your "500px and below" styles *before* your default styles, they will be overwritten.

This, and the syntactical issues that the others have pointed out, are combining to form your issue. See below:

```
.customer{
   float: left;
    width: 27%;
    height: 350px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px;
}

.dates{
      box-sizing: border-box;
      float: left;
      height: 350px;
     width: 22%;  
   padding: 15px;

}

.addressAndPhases{

      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-align: center;
      float: left;
      height: 650px;
     width: 22%;
    padding: 15px;

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .customer, .addressAndPhases, .dates {
        background-color: lightblue;
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an attribute css selector

```
[class*=".customer,.dates,.addressAndPhases"]
```

this would mean that you want to select all html tags which looks like:

```
<html_tag class=".customer,.dates,.addressAndPhases">
```

because of that you can not use "," as separator between different class names.
you have to separate those attributes selectors

```
[class="customer"], [class="dates"], [class="addressAndPhases"]
```

Answer (score 1):

replace to this `.customer,.dates,.addressAndPhases{ }` i think `class*`  wont work for multiple classes,

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .customer,.dates,.addressAndPhases{
        background-color: lightblue;
        width:100%;
    }
}

.customer{
   float: left;
    width: 27%;
    height: 350px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px;
}

.dates{
      box-sizing: border-box;
      float: left;
      height: 350px;
     width: 22%;  
   padding: 15px;

}

.addressAndPhases{

      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-align: center;
      float: left;
      height: 650px;
     width: 22%;
    padding: 15px;

}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="customer">
<customer></customer>
</div>
<div class="dates">
Dates comes here
</div>
<div class="addressAndPhases">
  Address and  phases comes here
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just write it like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .customer, .addressAndPhases, .dates {
     background-color: lightblue;
     width:100%;
   }
}
```